# Shuffling an array of (struct) in c

Tags: c

Can someone show me how to randomize an array of structures.
I've search online and seen many tutorial on how to randomsize array.
but i dont think they work in my scenario...

I kept getting error .exe stopped working .....

i assume the problem comes from

```
  card[i] = i + 1;
  card[i] = card[j];
  card[j] = temp;
```

Can someone please help me with my code, i am trying to randomise/shuffle the array card[]. for example:

card[0] is Ace
           heart
           red
card[1] is Two
           HEart
           red
... and so on
i want them to be
card[0] is some other card now.

```
struct Cards
{
  int suits;
  int values;
  int colour;
};

struct Cards card[52];

void printcard();
void filldeck(); /* Populates a deck of cards */
void printdeck();
void shuffle();

int main()
{
  /* code */
  printcard();
  filldeck();
  printdeck();
  shuffle();
  printdeck();
  return 0;
}


void shuffle()
{
   printf("%s\n\n", "---------------------- Shuffling deck ----------------------");
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int temp=0;
   int card[52];

   srand(time(NULL));

   for (i=0;i<52;i++)
   {
      j = (rand()%51) + 1;
      temp = card[i];
      card[i] = card[j];
      card[j] = temp;
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: i is uninitialized, then causes problem in declaring the local array in `shuffle`.

Comment: Now, i initialized i = 52, but the deck was not shuffled or randomized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the statements :

```
int i,j,temp;
int card[i];
```

but you have not initialized `i`. Therefore, you do not know how many elements array `card` will have and the behaviour of your program will be *undefined*, probably leading to segmentation fault. If you want your array to have `52` elements, initialize i to :

```
int i = 52;
```

and then declare :

```
int card[i];
```

***But actually***, the array you want to shuffle is the global array `struct Cards card[52]` , and not the array `cards` defined inside `shuffle` (see [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) on variables' scope). So try removing the following lines of code :

```
int card[i];
for (i=0;i<52;i++)
{
   card[i] = i + 1;
}
```

and see if the results are what you expected.

Comment: As you can see, i am new to C programming. Thx for the reply, it did solve the issue  but the deck was not randomized somehow..

Comment: @markh I answered to the question why your exe stops working. Randomizing your deck is a broad issue, you need to be more specific, explain your particular problem and you will get a specific answer.

Comment: My question is i wanna know how to randmoise this array card[0-51], i tried the method online, but it does not work in this scenario..

Comment: Thx for the edited answer, i can see what i done wrong here but after i delete the code you specify i get an error of: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Cards' from type 'int'

Comment: Thx for the help i figure them out!!! Thank you very much wish i can be a professional C developer one day like u hah.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with this code.

As Marievi says, this line

```
int card[i];
```

should be

```
int card[52];
```

because i is uninitialised at that point (you would have caught the error if you had compiled with lots of warnings enabled. If you are using gcc, compile with `-Wall`.

This line

```
j = (rand()%51) + 1;
```

actually gives you a pseudo random number between 1 and 51 inclusive, not 0 and 51 inclusive, which I think is what you want because it should be an index into the array.

Most importantly, the array you are shuffling is not the array with the cards in it. The line that should be `int card[52];` defines a new local array that exists only until the function returns and is then thrown away. It "shadows" your global card array for the duration of the function. If you delete it and get rid of the

```
for (i=0;i<52;i++)
{
   card[i] = i + 1;
}
```

you'll find your global card array is shuffled.

One more thing: you don't need to putthe colour of your cards in the `Card` struct. The colour is encoded by the suit. Hearts and diamonds are red; clubs and spades are black.

Comment: Thx for the reply, i'll change what needs to be change..and see if it works.

Comment: You might also look into the [Fisher Yates shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: this look intersting... i might implemetn this if i cant get it to work

Comment: Thank you too, ur a ledgend and i learn another lesson in my life thx!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already given, in order to randomize pack of cards, please observe following:
In function 'shuffle', you have created a local array 'card'; which eclipses global array 'card' of type 'struct Cards'.
What you need to do is use global 'card' in your shuffle function instead of local 'card'.
Local int array 'card' has life and visibility only inside shuffle().

HTH, Swanand

Comment: Plz share entire code, I will try to show the modifications needed.